# can someone help me with difficulties installing react-scripts? It leads to many error msgs I don't understand

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to `npm install` and running into dependency issues. The goal is to `npm start` and `npm run build` both of which were disrupted somehow.

This is among my first experiences handling dependency issues. The ideal answer includes the thought process one might use to address such a task, if possible, but it is just a bonus.

The root of the problem is that `npm start` gives me:

```
> postmassiv@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So its like ok just install react scripts! `npm install react-scripts`

I get this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: postmassiv@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0-0" from enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6
npm ERR! node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16
npm ERR!   dev enzyme-adapter-react-16@"^1.15.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

My error message after running `npm install`:

```
identical to above error
```

Note this error also occurs identically if i `npm install enzyme-adapter-react-16` which I figured would be worth trying.

Tried `npm install --save-dev @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17` but I get the same error msg. Note that this @wojtekmaj/ thing is made to replace `enzyme-adapter-react-17` until its ready.

So I tried `npm uninstall enzyme-adapter-react-16` and got:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.2" from @restart/context@2.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/context
npm ERR!     @restart/context@"^2.1.4" from react-bootstrap@1.6.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^1.6.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (prop-types-extra, react-router, react-router-dom, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha" from airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/airbnb-prop-types
npm ERR!   airbnb-prop-types@"^2.16.0" from enzyme-adapter-utils@1.13.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils
npm ERR!     enzyme-adapter-utils@"^1.13.1" from enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "postmassiv",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "prettier": {
        "tabWidth": 4
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.1.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6"
    },
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found success with the `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` flag. It installs and runs the server. I am now doing `npm audit fix --legacy-peer-deps`. The server `npm start`s correctly.

For pattern recognition: Seems the last person I saw to have this issue also used `ncu` as well. Think thats how I got the issue started in the first place